# Error while solving system of non-linear equations in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, equation, symbolic-math, non-linear

I am trying to solve system of non-linear equation simultaneously on MATLAB. I am getting the error:

> Comma separated list expansion has cell syntax for an array that is not a cell".

The screenshot of the error is attached:

> [image: error]

My code is given below:

```
syms x y z T
x1=1;
x2=1;
x3=1;
x4=1;
y1=1;
y2=1;
y3=1;
y4=1;
z1=1;
z2=1;
z3=1;
z4=1;
c=1;
t1=1;
t21=1;
t31=1;
t41=1;
eq1 = ((x1 - x)^2 + (y1 - y)^2 + (z1 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (c * t1) + (c * T)==0;
eq2 = ((x2 - x)^2 + (y2 - y)^2 + (z2 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (c * t21) - (c*t1) + (c*T)==0;
eq3 = ((x3 - x)^2 + (y3 - y)^2 + (z3 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (c * t31) - (c*t1) + (c*T)==0;
eq4 = ((x4 - x)^2 + (y4 - y)^2 + (z4 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (c * t41) - (c*t1) + (c*T)==0;
sol = solve(eq1, eq2, eq3, eq4);
xSol = sol.x
ySol = sol.y
zSol = sol.z
TSol = sol.T
```

Comment: I downvoted because error in a screenshot

Comment: Plus, this code does not error in my computer. Does not work either, but does not error.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the *complete* wording of the error message as text; not image. Also the error is not reproducible for me (on R2018a). Please include the version/release of MATLAB that you are using.

Answer (score 1):

When I run your code, there is no error in my MATLAB 2020a.

However it returns an empty solution. This is normal, your equations are not solvable. Check `eq1` and `eq2`. For your values, they are:

```
eq1 = ((1 - x)^2 + (1- y)^2 + (1 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (1) + (1 * T)==0;
eq2 = ((1 - x)^2 + (1- y)^2 + (1 - z)^2 )^1/2 - (2) + (1 * T)==0;
```

This has of course no solution,as you are basically saying:

```
eq1= ((1 - x)^2 + (1- y)^2 + (1 - z)^2 )^1/2 + (1 * T)==1
eq2= ((1 - x)^2 + (1- y)^2 + (1 - z)^2 )^1/2 + (1 * T)==2
```

Both can not coexist.

It is possible that you are using an older version of MATLAB that throws warning when solution does not exist and does not allow you to read it later, where your error happens.